# Heroku python Tutorial Won't run locally in windows

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, foreman

I'm trying to run the python heroku tutorial and it won't work in windows. This is from [this repository](https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started).

I posted this previously but I was able to get a more descriptive error message. It should be said that I've installed postgres.

Furthermore, I can't run it locally using the method defined in the git respository. Both the createdb and foreman commands don't work. This is despite installing foreman.

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django_postgrespool' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
u'base', u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
Error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: "Both the createdb and foreman commands don't work" - Can you post the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like python does not know what django-postgrespool is.

Perhaps it did not install properly. Check the output of `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django_postgrespool'

in your settings.py is what this is referring to.  For me i still dont know why this is causing a problem.  I've install psycopg2 and I even tried installing 'pip install django-postgrespool'. It worked once i commented out:

DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django_postgrespool'

this helps me run the app locally by using the

heroku local web -f Procfile.windows

Answer (score 0):

I was following the same tutorial and what worked for me was changing the settings.py file, this line:

```
# Enable Connection Pooling (if desired)
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django_postgrespool'
```

To this:

```
# Enable Connection Pooling (if desired)
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'
```